# Ordinal scale with unequal distribution

Tags: regression, panel-data, nonlinear-regression, ordinal-data, scales

Thank you for all the knowledge that has been shared in this forum so far! I have been going through numerous posts, but couldn't find a solution for my problem, so I'm opening a new question.

I am examining a large set of companies, for which over some years measurements have been taken (unbalanced panel). I am trying to find significant relationships between the "activity" of the companies in a certain field and other company characteristics, provided in a continuous distribution.

The dataset I have been given however doesn't measure this "activity" in absolute numbers, but rather assigns the companies into buckets of 0-4,9%, 5-14,9%, 15-24,9%, 25-49,9% and 50-100%. In a way, this is an ordinary scale, but since the buckets are not of the same size, I am not sure how to handle them.

The dependent variable I am currently considering is a continuous distribution of values between 0 and 1.

I would be incredibly thankful if you could point me into the right direction of how to process and handle my data and which regression model would be suited best.
Also, if I overlooked posts that have been previously discussed or you know good resources for this kind of problem, it would be fantastic if you could post them.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You know the bin-boundaries, so the scale is not merely ordinal. Binned data like these are  [*interval censored*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censoring_%28statistics%29#Types), and contain more information than purely ordinal data. There are techniques for such data, but if you had already thrown out the knowledge of the bin boundaries then you might consider ordinal regression methods.